# Batch updating forwarding addresses in Google Apps

Tags: web-applications, google-apps

Is there a way to batch add/update the forwarding address for all the users' email accounts in Google Apps?

We use Google Apps for group email forwarding for our school, and I have to add 90 or so new users complete with forwarding addresses in their email accounts. Adding the users en masse is easy, but updating their forwarding addresses requires manually logging into each account, which is tedious.

I understand having to wait for person on the receiving end of the forwarding to authorize the forwarding, but is there a way to automate the whole logging in and setting the forwarding address process?

And if this is the wrong place for this question, feel free to move/delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The email settings API allows you to get and set the user's forwarding address:

[http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.html#GA_email_forwarding_main][1]

I've written a Python app that can be used to do this:

https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM

Here's an example of setting an email forward

https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/ExamplesEmailSettings#setting-a-forward

Jay